# Codeigniter changing session value on click

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, onclick

Is there a way to change a session data CI on just one click, here is example

I have SRP/ENG a href button, i want when someone click on SRP to change jezik=1, and on other hand to change jezik=2 when someone one click ENG to jezik=2

I know i can accomplish that with

```
<?php $this->session->set_userdata('jezik', '1');?>
```

But how to do that only on click?

Txanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in one of your controllers and point your link to `your_controller/your_function`. In the function you can change your session data. Afterwards you can redirect the user to wherever you want.

If you do not want to reload the whole page you can use ajax to load the controller/function, but you will have to load *something*.